# Troca de Apache para IIS: como exibir erros

Tags: php, html, iis

Tenho uma página web bastante básica(tipo um questionário), em que no final guarda a informação numa base de dados MySql.

Enquanto estava alocada no Apache(fornecido pelo xampp) estava a funcionar, agora que passei para um servidor IIS a parte do post deixou de funcionar.

O fluxo é:

Questionário.html > metodo post -> insert.php -> Fim.html

-Já instalei o php e está a funcionar (Testei com a função `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` na raiz e funciona)

É necessário configurar mais alguma coisa?

Como posso fazer o debug para verificar mais propriamente o erro?
O único resultado que consigo ver é como se o servidor estivesse em baixo...

logs do IIS(últimos 4):

```
2017-01-12 16:35:35 ::1 GET /survey/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/survey/ 404 0 2 1
2017-01-12 16:35:35 ::1 GET /survey/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/survey/ 404 0 2 0
2017-01-12 16:35:35 ::1 GET /survey/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/survey/ 404 0 2 0
2017-01-12 16:36:01 ::1 POST /survey/insert.php - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/survey/ 500 0 0 2069
```

Comment: Tinha um arquivo htaccess antes? o que é exatamente deixou de funcionar? é uma tela em branco? o código fonte é exibido na tela?

Comment: não, não tinha nenhum desses ficheiros (se existia era algum criado por defeito). A página depois de carregar no botão "save" fica como se o servidor estivesse em baixo... o link fica qualquer coisa como localhost/insert.php mas a pagina não aparece, nem o print do `echo` que está logo na parte superior do ficheiro faz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, garanta que o PHP emita os erros incluindo estas duas linhas no seu código:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Atenção para que nenhum código (de um framework, por exemplo) desfaça isso depois!

Se mesmo assim os erros não aparecerem, verifique as configurações do IIS. Nas opções de páginas de erros, é ativar o modo "erros detalhados" ou "erros detalhados em requisições locais".